# Algorithm to group connected graphs

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

I am working on an algorithm, which should group connected Arcs. The situation is described via code examples below.

I have Arcs:

```
public class Arc
{
    public Point StartPoint { get; set; }
    public Point EndPoint { get; set; }
    public bool Visited { get; set; }
    public Arc Successor { get; set; }
    public Arc Predecessor { get; set; }
}
```

that consist of Points:

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((Point)obj);
    }

    protected bool Equals(Point other)
    {
        return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
        return (X.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Given these Points and resulting Arcs:

```
var p1 = new Point {X = 0, Y = 0};
var p2 = new Point { X = 0, Y = 1 };
var p3 = new Point { X = 0, Y = 2 };
var p4 = new Point { X = 1, Y = 0 };
var p5 = new Point { X = 1, Y = 1 };

var arc1 = new Arc { StartPoint = p1, EndPoint = p2};
var arc2 = new Arc { StartPoint = p4, EndPoint = p5};
var arc3 = new Arc { StartPoint = p2, EndPoint = p3};
```

I would like to end up with groups of connected Arcs as a list of list:

```
var arcListOfList = new List<List<Arc>>();
```

This is the crude algorithm I came up with so far:

```
foreach (var arc in arcList)
{
    var successor = arcList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartPoint.Equals(arc.EndPoint));
    var predecessor = arcList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EndPoint.Equals(arc.StartPoint));
    arc.Successor = successor;
    arc.Predecessor = predecessor;
}

Arc next;
do
{
    next = arcList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Visited == false);
    var temp = new List<Arc>();

    if (next == null) continue;
    do
    {
        next.Visited = true;
        temp.Add(next);
        if (next.Successor != null)
        {
        next = next.Successor;
        }
        else
        {
        break;
        }
    } while (true);

    arcListOfList.Add(temp);
} while (next != null);
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestions to improve it.

Comment: Try writing a description of your problem and algorithm at the top of your post. That will likely catch the eye of potential reviewers more easily. It will also look nicer on tag pages (right now it just says " I have Arcs: ... ").

Comment: `return (X.GetHashCode() * 397) ^ Y.GetHashCode();`
Could someone give a quick reason why this is unchecked, and if 397 is just a magic number, why pick exactly 397?

Comment: And for clarification, is there only 1 arc in and 1 arc out of any given point? If this is a rule it needs to be clear in code, if there can be multiple in/out then the code is incorrect...

Comment: Answering my first comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/102742/why-is-397-used-for-resharper-gethashcode-override

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to leave off suggesting anything about the algorithm for now as I don't fully understand what you want from it. Instead, I'm going to talk about your `Point` class in laborious depth...

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
```

I would argue that a point should be immutable - i.e. it doesn't change after you've created it. I would implement with full readonly properties:

```
private readonly int x;
public int X { get { return x; } }

private readonly int y;
public int Y { get { return y; } }

public Point(int x, int y)
{
   this.x = x;
   this.y = y
}
```

However, most people would let you off with private set auto properties:

```
public int X { get; private set; }
```

Let's look at your `Equals` implementations

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    return obj.GetType() == GetType() && Equals((Point)obj);
}

protected bool Equals(Point other)
{
    return X.Equals(other.X) && Y.Equals(other.Y);
}
```

Firstly, `bool Equals(Point other)` -> that's `IEquatable<Point>` if made public so your class should implement that:

```
public class Point : IEquatable<Point>
```

Now, simplify the `object.Equals` override:

```
public override bool Equals(Object obj)
{
    return Equals(obj as Point);
}
```

And sharpen up the `IEquatable<Point>.Equals`:

```
public bool Equals(Point other)
{
    return other != null
            && other.X == X
            && other.Y == Y;
}
```

We should also override the `==` and `!=` operators so that we're sure we are consistent with out equality:

```
public static bool operator ==(Point left, Point right)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
    {
        return object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
    }

    return left.Equals(right);
}

public static bool operator !=(Point left, Point right)
{
    if (object.ReferenceEquals(left, null))
    {
        return !object.ReferenceEquals(right, null);
    }

    return !left.Equals(right);
}
```

Then you have a nice immutable class for your `Point` with consistent equality behaviour... Phew!

**Edit**

As EBrown pointed out in the comments, `Point` is a perfect fit for being a struct. It's less than 16 bytes, immutable and (0, 0) is a perfectly valid value (i.e. unitialized).

Comment: It could be argued that `Point` should be a `struct` as well.

Comment: @EBrown - Yes it almost certainly should be. I forgot to mention that as I was going through. I've updated now.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about this

> ```
> Arc next;
> do
> {
>     next = arcList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Visited == false);
>     var temp = new List<Arc>();
>
>     if (next == null) continue;
>     do
>     {
>         next.Visited = true;
>         temp.Add(next);
>         if (next.Successor != null)
>         {
>         next = next.Successor;
>         }
>         else
>         {
>         break;
>         }
>     } while (true);
>
>     arcListOfList.Add(temp);
> } while (next != null);
> ```

- `temp` is almost always a bad name for a variable, at least if it stands on its own. Naming it `tempArcList` would be better but not ideal.

  You should try to come up with a good and meaningful name.
- `if (next == null) continue;` this `continue` should be a break because the `do..while` will just end if `next != null`.
- Using braces `{}` for single statement `if,` else` will help you to make your code less error prone. At least you have put the statement at the same line, which is a good start. Using braces would also (IMHO) improve the readability because it makes the statement more prominent.
- If you invert the `if (next.Successor != null)` condition, you would reduce the horizontal spacing, hence improving readability.
- you should always declare your variables as near as possible to their usage.

Implementing the above points would lead to this

```
Arc next;
do
{
    next = arcList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Visited == false);

    if (next == null) { break; }

    var currentArcs= new List<Arc>();
    do
    {
        next.Visited = true;
        currentArcs.Add(next);
        if (next.Successor == null) { break; }

        next = next.Successor;

    } while (true);

    arcListOfList.Add(currentArcs);
} while (next != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume there's no rule against having multiple arcs going in/out of a single point, as there's nothing stopping it currently.

If it's possible to have multiple arcs entering/ exiting a single point, we need to change:

```
public class Arc
{
    ...
    public Arc Successor { get; set; }
    public Arc Predecessor { get; set; }
}
```

to this:

```
public class Arc
{
    ...
    public List<Arc> Successors { get; set; }
    public List<Arc> Predecessors { get; set; }
}
```

From there you'll need to do something like:

```
foreach (var arc in arcList){
    if (!arcAlreadyInAnyGroup(arc, arcListOfList)) {
        var arcGroup = new List<Arc>(); //empty the group each time
        getGroupOfArcs(ref arc, ref arcGroup);
        arcListOfList.Add(arcGroup);
    }
}
```

I'm not going to make arcAlreadyInAnyGroup, it can just be some linq to check if arc is anywhere in arcListOfList.

```
//Traverse outwards from single arc recursively
private void getGroupOfArcs(ref Arc startArc, ref List<Arc> arcGroup){
    startArc.visited = true;
    arcGroup.add(startArc);
    foreach (var forwardArc in startArc.Successors){
        if (!forwardArc.visited){
            getGroupOfArcs(ref forwardArc, ref arcGroup);
        }
    }
    foreach (var backwardsArc in startArc.Predecessors){
        if (!backwardsArc.visited){
            getGroupOfArcs(ref backwardsArc, ref arcGroup);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm sure there's a few code smells in there, but you get the idea. Just traverse out from one arc, and add any connected arcs to the group. The runtime here could also be improved a lot I think.