# Find unconnected nodes of a graph

Tags: algorithm, ruby, graph

It is a set of edges of a graph given. An edge is given as an array of its endpoints, e.g. `[:a, :b]`. The array can contain an arbitrary amount of endpoints. Therefore `[]` and `[:b, :c, :d]` are also valid edges.

I want to find all islands which means that I looking for unconnected sets of nodes. Here is my Ruby solution.

```
e = [[:a, :b],[:c, :d],[:b, :c, :e], [:f, :g]]
n = e.flatten.uniq

def islands(edges)
  edges.reduce([]) do |islands, edge|
    matches = islands.select { |island| island.any? { |node| edge.include?(node) } }

    if !matches.empty?
      island = matches.shift
      islands.delete_if { |i| matches.include?(i) }

      island.concat(matches.flatten)
      island.concat(edge)
      island.uniq!
    else
      islands << edge
    end

    islands
  end
end

puts islands(e).inspect
# => [[:a, :b, :c, :d, :e], [:f, :g]]
```

Is there room for improvement?

Comment: Found a similar [question for C#](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/97129/51432)

Comment: I am too lazy to write an answer, but with a quick-union algorithm it would be much, much faster. https://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/01UnionFind.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
if !matches.empty?
```

equals

```
if matches.any?
```

And the second is preferable, cause you don't have negation.

Comment: [nil].empty? == [nil].any?